# Bat file includes

Tags: batch-file, include

Can one bat file be included in another?  I have variables set in one bat file and want to include the other commands by calling a second bat file.  I know about the call command.  Is there an include command that is saying execute the remainder of the bat file from what is contained in that second bat file?

Comment: How does call not do what you want?

Comment: @Neil, the second file that I want to include does not have all the information to execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a file variablefile.bat along the lines of

```
set var1 = value
set var2 = value
```

then you can add the line

```
call variablefile.bat
```

to another file to import the variables. You can access the variables as usual.

Comment: Thanks! That's the obvious solution.  I hadn't thought of it.